# What was it like to travel to Easter Island?

Tags: transportation, ships

Reviewing the question "[How did people travel to remote islands like Easter Island?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61/1401), @dotancohen has a few additional questions:

- How long did they sail?
- How could they row for so long (exhaustion)?
- How many rowers (crew) were on board?
- How big were the canoes?
- How could they have room for enough supplies (food and water)?

Comment: This was a set of questions that were entered as an answer to another question.  Rather than telling someone to move them, I just moved them to a new question. Closure is fine with me.